# After login the logout link is not appearing

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I made a joomla jquery ajax login  combined with a component entry, but when a user is logged in and redirected through ajax to a URL, my Login button is still there and it is functional.

How can I check the status of the user and if the user is a guest, then display the logout link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about joomla but when the user logs in you need to store a session variable or a cookie etc. that you can access and check if they are logged in and if they are then hide the login link and show the logout link and vice versa.

Comment: Yep is it so. <?php if ($type == 'logout') : ?>

Comment: I can't say without seeing how your code works. When the user signs in successfully then you could put in `<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
?>` then on each page you can do `if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {echo "<a href=\"logout.php\""}`. I would suggest keeping the if statement in an external file that can be included on every page. Hope that makes sense?